# get Linkified text from textview-android...?

Tags: android, textview, linkify

I have a textview in my android application.

```
    textView.setText(message);
    Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.ALL);
```

with this code it identify phone number,email address, weblink etc. and highlight it for click, so appropriate intent call.

I want to fetch whatever linkify in my textview store it in an array
example

if my textview contains `"Hello, this is deer, my phone number is 9988776655 and email id is abc@gmail.com and weburl is www.abc.com"` string

then I want to fetch **"9988776655","abc@gmail.com","www.abc.com"** and store it in array,
is it possible...!?!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [TextView#getUrls](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getUrls%28%29) after the call to `Linkify` like this:

```
URLSpan spans[] = textView.getUrls();
for(URLSpan span: spans) {
    Log.d(TAG, span.getURL());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use textView.getUrls() . Then loop over this array and use URLSpan.getUrls() to get individual link